# Problemas al abrir un pdf desde una unidad en la red

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, windows-server

Lo que quiero lograr es visualizar en el navegador los pdf ubicados en una unidad de red (carpeta compartida) en `windows server 2016` y `php versión 7.3.3`.

Desde mi equipo de desarrollo con `windows 10` y `php versión 7.3.4` funciona correctamente, el problema se produce al ejecutar desde el servidor, no muestra los archivos pdf, trabajo con laravel.

En el archivo de rutas laravel `web.php` tengo la siguiente ruta;

```
Route::get('documentos/{ruta}', function ($ruta) {
    $file = 'R:'.$ruta; //R es la unidad de red, carpeta compartida
    $filename = 'R:'.$ruta;
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    @readfile($file);
});
```

Si el archivo esta en `disco local C:` lo muestra correctamente.
he intentado creando un link simbólico con `mklink` en la carpeta `public` del proyecto, un link simbólico en `disco local C:` pero no he tenido éxito, siempre es lo mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución en este [sitio](https://rstopup.com/el-cambio-de-php-permisos-de-escritura-en-xampp-en-windows-7.html) específicamente en esta parte de la respuesta aceptada

> Usted sólo tiene que encontrar, en virtud de la cual el nombre de usuario de apache se está ejecutando (a través de Herramientas Administrativas, Servicios) y añadir permisos de lectura/escritura para el usuario en la carpeta correspondiente.

En mi caso el servidor pertenece a un DOMINIO y el servicio de apache se inicia con Sistema local el cual no tiene ningún tipo de permiso sobre esta carpeta compartida, por este motivo siempre arrojaba error `404`.
[image: Instalacion del servicio Apache por defecto]

Cambios que realice a mi proyecto:
1.-Decidi no utilizar una unidad de red, en cambio utilizar un vinculo en disco local C: con el siguiente comando en el símbolo de sistema de windows (`mklink /d documentos_pdf \\NOMBRESERVIDOR\NOMBRECARPETA`).
2.-Modificar el usuario del servicio de Apache.
[image: Propiedades del servicio Apache Modificado]

Mi código php quedo de la siguiente manera donde `{ruta}` llega con formato `2018-12-305.pdf`:

```
Route::get('documentos/{ruta}', function ($ruta) {
        $arr_ruta = explode('-',$ruta);

        $arr_meses = [
            '01' => '1 Enero',
            '02' => '2 Febrero',
            '03' => '3 Marzo',
            '04' => '4 Abril',
            '05' => '5 Mayo',
            '06' => '6 Junio',
            '07' => '7 Julio',
            '08' => '8 Agosto',
            '09' => '9 Septiembre',
            '10' => '10 Octubre',
            '11' => '11 Noviembre',
            '12' => '12 Diciembre',
        ];

        $ruta_pdf = $arr_ruta[0] . '-' . $arr_ruta[1] . '-' . str_pad($arr_ruta[2], 7, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $file = 'C:documento_pdf/' . $arr_ruta[0] . '/' . $arr_meses[$arr_ruta[1]] . '/' . $ruta_pdf;
        $filename = 'C:documento_pdf/' . $arr_ruta[0] . '/' . $arr_meses[$arr_ruta[1]] . '/' . $ruta_pdf;
        if(file_exists($file)){
            header('Content-type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
            @readfile($file);
        }else{
            abort(404);
        }
    })->name('ver_pdf');
```